change in viewIndex should rerender the view but it does not
what am I missing? This change in viewIndex should trigger rerender of view but it does not.
ViewIndex will change the index of user to use for profileView and it will trigger rerendering.
import SwiftUI

struct ExploreProfileView: View {
    @State private var userProfiles: [User]
    @State private var viewIndex: Int = 0
    
    init(profiles: [User]) {
        self._userProfiles = State(initialValue: profiles)
    }
    
    private func updateViewIndex() {
        if viewIndex < userProfiles.count - 1 {
            viewIndex += 1
        } else {
            viewIndex = 0
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            
            if userProfiles.isEmpty {
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("No profile(s) to view")
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                
            } else {
                
                ZStack {
                    ProfileView(user: userProfiles[viewIndex])
                    
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text("Like")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    updateViewIndex()
                                }
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text("Pass")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    updateViewIndex()
                                }
                            
                            Spacer()
                        }.padding()
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

I identified that viewIndex is changed correctly but it does not trigger rerendering of the view.
What is causing this bug?
I tried to rerender the view after the change in viewIndex and I expected the view to change in every change in viewIndex.

Works for me in my tests. How do you declare User, and what do you display in ProfileView

Use let not @State var and remove the init, eg
struct ExploreProfileView: View {
    //@State private var userProfiles: [User]
    let userProfiles: [User]
    @State private var viewIndex: Int = 0
    
    //init(profiles: [User]) {
    //    self._userProfiles = State(initialValue: profiles)
    //}


